# Метод video.save

Tags: vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь прикрепить видео с ютюб к посту по такому алгоритму:

1. Делаю запрос к video.save со ссылкой на ролик и другими необходимыми параметрами
2. Получаю ответ с vid и upload_url
3. Отправляю пустой запрос на upload_url
4. В результате всегда получаю ответ "error_code":15,"error_msg":"video already imported"
5. При добавлении в attachments к wall.post такое видео остается на бесконечной "обработке, пожалуйста подождите"

Я понимаю, что до меня эти видео уже 100500 раз прикрепляли, если проблема конкретно в этом (или в чем?). Но какими методами тогда выковыривать из недр ВК нужный мне ролик?

Comment: Что будет, если просто в тексте поста поместить ссылку на YT видео?
Наскоро проверил, у меня для сто-раз-загруженного видео обращение на upload_url возвращает `{"response":1}`

Comment: @Sergiks В этом случае она будет выглядеть обыкновенной ссылкой,  а не встроенным роликом. Такая же ситуация, если вставить ссылку в attachment поста. Оба варианта не устраивают - хочу добиться возможности воспроизведения без необходимости переходов.

upd: Можете показать минимальный отрезок кода на любом языке?

Comment: @Pavel каким образом вы аттачмент делаете? Только что послал запрос вида `https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=123456&message=MyMessageOnTheWall&attachments=video123456_987654&access_token=666666666666`, где `123456_987654` - `owner_id` и `video_id` соответственно которое вернуло `video.save`...И все отработало........... и зачем `Отправляю пустой запрос на upload_url` ??? что это за странный шаг?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский итоговая строка wall.post выглядит так же. Аттач  прикрепляю к посту в таком виде (C#):      var att =  "video" + json["response"]["owner_id"] + "_" + json["response"]["vid"];
Фотографии прикрепляю точно так же - с ними проблем нет. Пустой запрос отправляю, видимо, для подтверждения, следуя документации к video.save, раздел link

Comment: В общем, получаю одно из двух теперь в ответ от upload_url :
На ролики вида https://youtu.be/xxxx - Security breach 3;
На ролики вида https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxx - {"error_code":15,"error_msg":"video already imported"};
На другие формы ютуба - что-то вроде видео не найдено.

Причем с фотографиями проблем нет вообще

Comment: @Pavel я [пробовал](https://vk.com/dev/video.save?params[name]=No%20name&params[is_private]=0&params[wallpost]=0&params[link]=https%3A%2F%2Fyoutu.be%2FhWSt_q7M3zI&params[no_comments]=0&params[repeat]=0&params[v]=5.44) на странице метода вводить ссылку на YT видео, и потом открывал полученный `upload_url`.

Comment: @Sergiks В их песочнице у меня тоже всё нормально, с любыми версиями api. Этот факт вкупе с невнятными возвращаемыми ответами, о которых  даже google особо не слышал, вызывают недоумение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась сменой метода запроса к video.save с GET на POST. В документации об этом не нашел ни слова, но тем не менее, если кто столкнется - обратите внимание.